# use of uninitialized value. How can I fix this error?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssh, command-line, terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use warnings;
use strict;

#my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l /home/$usr")
# Making an ssh connection with user-password authentication
# 1) construct the object
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
  host => "host", 
  password=> 'pwd', 
  user => 'user', 
  raw_pty => 1
  #Expect=>log_file("finally.txt")
   );


# 2) logon to the SSH server using those credentials.
# test the login output to make sure we had success
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
  if ($login_output !~ /Welcome/) {
   die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
    }



# disable terminal translations and echo on the SSH server
# executing on the server the stty command:
$ssh->exec("stty raw -echo");




my $stdout = $ssh->send(chr(13));
my $stdout2 = $ssh->send("SDT-FI");
my $stdout3 = $ssh->send("ENG");
my $stdout4 = $ssh->send('SORT FI-WIP "84144"');
my $stdout5 = $ssh->send(chr(13)); 
my $stdout6 = $ssh->send("OFF");
my $stdout7 = $ssh->send(chr(13)); 

print($stdout3);

#$expect->log_file("adp-n.txt");

#y $line;
# returns the next line, removing it from the input stream:
# while ( defined ($line = $ssh->read_all()) ) {
#   print $line . "\n";  

#}
```

So i am trying to print $stdout3 so i can get information about the output
but i keep getting " use of uninitialized value $stdout3 in print at connnn3.pl line 50"

is there something in my code wrong?
how can i fix this?

UPDATE, SOLVED!
The reason why it was returning "use of uninitialized value" was because the function

```
send()
```

Is void, so instead i used

```
exec()
```

And that solved it

Comment: what happens when you have `print($stdout2)` (and other numbers)? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it gives me the same error

Comment: Please don't edit comments like _solved_ into your question. Instead, answer your question yourself with a proper solution so others can benefit. Stack Overflow is not a forum, but a Q and A site.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation of Net::SSH::Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect#void-send($string)-sends-$string-to-the-SSH-server,-returns-nothing):

> void send($string) - sends $string to the SSH server, returns nothing

Thus, `send` obviously returns nothing (void) and that's why you get this warning when trying to print the (non-existing) return value of `send`.  If you want to get data back from the server use `peek`, `eat`, `read_all` or similar as documented.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @popeonhabbo123: did you look at the documentation yet? It contains examples.

Comment: I solved it, thanks :) i used exec instead and it worked. Thanks for letting me know that send is void :) it really helped